# how to fix a erro python tesseract error?

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I need to use python tesseract to extract text from a photo:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image


img = Image.open('stest.png')
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'D:\\python\\venv\\Scripts\\pytesseract.exe'

file_name = img.filename
file_name = file_name.split(".")[0]


text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img,lang=None, config='')
print(text)

with open(f'{file_name}.txt', 'w') as text_file:
    text_file.write(text)
```

But the error appears as if it is not related to my code:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\pybotavito\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img,lang=None, config='')
  File "D:\python\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 413, in image_to_string
    return {
  File "D:\python\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 416, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "D:\python\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 284, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "D:\python\venv\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 260, in run_tesseract
    raise TesseractError(proc.returncode, get_errors(error_string))
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (2, 'Usage: pytesseract [-l lang] input_file')
```

Answer (score 0):

From the README page of `pytesseract`,

> ```py
> # If you don't have tesseract executable in your PATH, include the following:
> pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'<full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable>'
> # Example tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'
> ```

This line must point to the `tesseract` executable, NOT to the `pytesseract` python executable. Try to set the correct executable path. There is an example on where to find the executable in the comment bellow the corresponding line.